# Как реализовать поиск по базе данных по параметру?

Tags: mysql, javafx

Как сделать поиск, если ввели город, то выводился объект из базы данных?

Это контроллер для страницы поиска

```
package sample;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class SearchController {
@FXML
private ResourceBundle resources;

@FXML
private URL location;

@FXML
private Button backBtn;

@FXML
private TextArea search_area;

@FXML
private TextField searchCityField;

@FXML
private Button searchBtn;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    searchBtn.setOnAction(event -> {
        String city = searchCityField.getText().trim();
        searchCity(city);
    });
}

public void searchCity(String city){
    DataBaseHandler db =new DataBaseHandler();
    Flights flights = new Flights();
    flights.setArrive(city);
    ResultSet rs = db.getFlightCity(flights);

    int count = 0;


    try{
        while (rs.next()){
            count++;
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(count >= 1){
        search_area.setText(String.valueOf(flights));
    }
}
```

}

Это метод отвечающий за действие базы данных

```
public ResultSet getFlightCity(Flights flights){
        ResultSet rs = null;

    String select = "SELECT * FROM " + Const.FLIGHTS_TABLE + " WHERE " +
            Const.FLIGHTS_ARRIVE + "=?" ;

    try{
        PreparedStatement prSt = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(select);
        prSt.setString(1, flights.getArrive());
        rs = prSt.executeQuery();
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs;
}
```

Выводит сам город, но остальные значения null. Помогите пожалуйста реализовать поиск.

Comment: А что еще должно выводиться, если вы сделали объект flights, установили в него город, потом дали пустую нагрузку, которую никак не использовали и вывели этот объект с установленным городом?

Comment: должен выводится сам объект, пожалуйста помогите, я просто новичек

Comment: Вы считате количество данных, вернувшихся из базы, но нигде их не используете

Comment: ну как мне это сделать?